# Passing Parse objectID created on prepareForSegue

Tags: swift, parse-platform, save, segue, objectid

I am trying to pass the Parse Class "Conversation" objectId after it's created to another View Controller. When I check the data does not pass to the variable I point to.

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object(s) to the new view controller.

    let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as ConversationViewController


    //Save Conversation Data
    var convo = PFObject(className: "Conversation")
    convo.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (success != nil) {
            //Save Selected Person
            participant["conversationId"] = convo.objectId as String!
            participant.saveInBackground()

        }
        else{
            NSLog("%@", error)
        }

    }

    //Trying to Pass convo.objectId
    destinationVC.newConversationId = convo.objectId as String!

}
```

Comment: You can't parse an objectId for an object that doesn't exist. After you create it you will have to do a query to obtain the Id or simply force the objectId on the object by specifying an objectId when you save it,but this won't work if your using this same code for multiple saves

Comment: @Stephen - feel free mark the answer correct if it solved the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it created two segues- I need to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that `convo.objectId` is not set at the point where you use it.  It gets set in the completion block of `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:`, but that block runs *after* the code that appears underneath it.

So what to do?  If the next vc needs the convo object to be saved before it runs, then the correct pattern is to run the segue after the save.  Find the point in your code where you are initiating the segue and replace it with the `convo.saveInBackgroundWithBlock`.  Then do the `performSegue` from within that block.

**Edit** - Here's how doing this looks in objective-C.  In either language, in order to do this, you must initiate the segue from code.  Say you have the segue painted from a table view cell in IB (or storyboard) to the next view controller.  Delete that segue, and control-drag a new one starting from the *view controller which contains the table*.  (Select the view controller in IB and drag from there.  Then, using the attributes inspector, give that segue and identifier, say, "ConvoSegue").

```
// since a table selection that starts the action, implement the selection delegate method
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // we decide here that the convo object must be saved, and
    // a segue should happen to another vc that needs the convo object:

    var convo = PFObject(className: "Conversation")
    convo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // now that convo is saved, we can start the segue
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ConvoSegue" sender:convo];
        } else {
            // don't segue, stay here and deal with the error
        }
    }];
}
```

Notice in the above, we passed convo as the sender of the segue.  This allows access to it in `prepareForSegue`.  You can skip that if convo is a property of this view controller.

Now prepare for segue looks like yours, except without the asynch save...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    // we don't need the selected row from the table view, because we have 
    // the convo object as the sender
    // let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row

    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as ConversationViewController

    // sorry, back to objective-c here:
    PFObject *convo = (PFObject)AnyObject;  // need a cast to use properly in objective-c

    // deleted your save logic.  just pass convo's id
    //Trying to Pass convo.objectId
    destinationVC.newConversationId = convo.objectId as String!
}
```

Comment: Thanks danh, that was my thinking- it is just a matter of understanding how to do it. Any examples?

Comment: I don't speak swift fluently.  Can I show you in objective-c?

Comment: Sure, I might be able to interpret it in Swift.

Comment: Okay.  How do you decide that you want to perform the segue.  Do you trigger it in code?

Comment: No, it's not triggered in code. There is only one segue from the current VC to the ConversationViewController

Comment: Painted from a button or a table cell?  That will need to change.  I'm editing the answer right now.

Comment: @Stephen - I figured out from the context that you've painted from a table.  See my half-objective-c updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, I think this will do!

Comment: yeah, sorry- it's still not working. Also, it's executing two segue animations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68183/discussion-between-danh-and-stephen).